# Как получить информацию от пользователя в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

хочу получить информацию от пользователя в телеграмм боте, что-то типа

```
a = input()
```

как реализовать такое в боте при помощи pytelegrambotapi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправьте мне сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    print('id пользователя', message.chat.id)
    print('имя пользователя', message.from_user.first_name)
    print('фамилия пользователя', message.from_user.last_name)
    print('никнейм пользователя', message.from_user.username)
    print('сообщение пользователя', message.text)
```

Один из вариантов.

Comment: и как это работает?

Comment: `register_next_step_handler` ожидает ввода от пользователя и вызывает следующую функцию указанную как аргумент, в моем примере это `start_2()`. А в ней выводятся данные пользователя взятые из объекта `message`

Comment: не обязательно ждать второго сообщения, в переменной msg уже будут все данные, например msg.chat.username